# Connection Pool Closed when using Spark-MongoDB Connector

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am facing an error when I try to read from mongoDB with Mmngo-spark `connector_2.11:2.2.7`.

After initializing spark context mongodb accept connection, right after i try to read collections from it and I get:

```
INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [localhost:27017]
INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, 
serverValue:17}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

MongoDB Container Output:

```
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.18.0.1:65513 #6 
(2 connections now open)
I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.18.0.1:65515 #7 
(3 connections now open) I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 
172.18.0.1:65515 (2 connections now open) I NETWORK  [conn6] end 
connection 172.18.0.1:65513 (1 connection now open)
```

All components mongoDB, Spark master & worker are container in Docker (necessary ports exposed and I can connect to all using shell).

So i really don't know whats going wrong

I have a running spark cluster with one master and one worker, all nodes have the necessary dependencies for connecting spark to mongoDB

```py
 MongoDBsession = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("MongoDB Export to Hive") \
        .master("spark://localhost:7077") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name.collection_name?readPreference=primaryPreferred") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner","MongoSamplePartitioner") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.7") \
        .getOrCreate()


    df_mongoDB_messageLogs = MongoDBsession.read \
        .format("mongo") \
        .option("database","db_name") \
        .option("collection","collection_name") \
        .load()
```

UPDATE:

This happens only when submit the spark application to the spark-cluster (localhost:7077). 
IF I run spark-submit with master=local there is no problem reading data from mongoDB. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in the end it was not even a error of mongodb or spark. It was just a docker thing. I could not access mongodb with localhost.